# How to format buffer to JSON in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, buffer

I am getting a buffer message from a stream in Nodejs app.How can i decode this to string/JSON ?

```
sock.on("message", function(topic, message) {


  console.log(
    "received a message ",
    message
  );
});
```

I have tried to format to utf8 using toString() and then tried using buffer npm module but could not find a way.I also searched for similar questions but no luck

When I tried the following sample code in python I am able to see the output in XML. But how can I achieve the same in nodejs.

python code:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from io import BytesIO
import zmq
import xmltodict
import pprint
import json

context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect("tcp location")
subscriber.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "topicname")
while true:

   multipart = subscriber.recv_multipart()
   address = multipart[0]
   contents = b''.join(multipart[1:])
   contents = GzipFile('','r',0,BytesIO(contents)).read()
   contents = contents.decode('UTF-8').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
   print(contents)


subscriber.close()
context.term()
```

formatted outputed 
[image]

[image]

Comment: with all those `00` and `08` etc ... it won't be a string - what is the data supposed to be?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added some additional information in the question. When I tried some python sample code to decode the stream of data to XML. Basically, the data would be in XML Which can be later parsed to JSON.

Comment: oh ... it's gzipped, that would've been useful information in the original question! - I'm sure there's a gzip library for node - you just have to find it

Comment: Thanks , I found this module zlib to be useful , But when i use the data is not in xml.Guess i need to do further more parsing. Can you refer me to some examples if possible?  

`const x = zlib.Unzip(message);`

Comment: nope, never used gzip library in node